# JS change especially date format from string

Tags: javascript, date

It is the first time when I met some of the bad example of data format.
All date goes for me regarding to a region of a customer.
I cannot change it. I got string:

```
var str = "23.01.2019 23:05:58";
```

in order to get

```
var dt = new Date(str);
```

I need to execute at least

```
str.replace(/./g,'/');
```

But got a weird result. (tried "split" and "join") also nothing.
Thanks a lot for any help

Comment: Consider using moment.js - It's very good at handling date formatting. I can't say for sure it handles this specific case, but it just might.

Comment: in this case, I can use just Javascript (without any libraries)

Answer (score 1):

The `.` in your regular expression means **any** character.

Try this instead...

```
str.replace(/\./g,'/');
```

By using `\.` you're "escaping" the dot and saying "this has to be a dot character"

Comment: thanks, you are right!
It works good

Comment: You're welcome @BladeRunner - good luck with the rest of your project

Comment: While this answers the issue of replacing "." with "/", it doesn't answer the bigger question of parsing the string to a Date. The OP format and that generated by this answer are not compatible with ECMA-262, so parsing is implementation dependent. If this answer "works" with *Date.parse*, it's just luck (e.g. Safari returns "Invalid Date" for both formats).